# marcar item seleccionado gridView android

Tags: android, android-studio

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:columnWidth="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp">
```

Tengo ese gridView y quiero pintar el borde de la imagen cuando la selecciona, se me ocurrieron cosas para hacer pero nada propio del componente.
Cada imagen del grid es un xml y tengo el metodo del evento con cada vez q hace click sobre una imagen del gridview, me falta pintarlo.

Comment: se puede con layerDrawable. Pon el metodo onclick donde selecciona un elemento del grid